# android async task cancellation error

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am having problem in cancelling the async task or may be I am cancelling it in wrong way I have an main activity In which there are two activity One and two and the problem is that

I want to cancel async task in one activity so that when activity two is started it can again be started or executed and app will not get crashed.

OneActivity

```
public class OneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private RemoteDataTask tsk;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.gpsicon);

    AsyncTask tsk = new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}


private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OneActivity.this);


        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ......");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "One");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.one_list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(OneActivity.this,
                R.layout.one_row_item);

        for (ParseObject one : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) one.get("onec"));
        }

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        tsk.cancel(true);

    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    tsk.cancel(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

TwoActivity

```
public class TwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private RemoteDataTask tsk;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.gpsicon);

    AsyncTask tsk = new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}


private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TwoActivity.this);


        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ......");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Two");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.two_list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TwoActivity.this,
                R.layout.two_row_item);

        for (ParseObject two : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) two.get("twoc"));
        }

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();


        tsk.cancel(true);

    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    tsk.cancel(true);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance I just want to simple know how to cancel async task after the work is completed.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to simple know how to cancel async task after the work is
>   completed

You don't need to cancel (take care of it), AsyncTask will automatically terminated after finishing work. like after execution of `onPostExecute()` if available else after `doInBackground()`.

This is how `Asynctask` works in android.

Comment: problem is coming when i go back from oneactivity and then open the two activity then app crashes and when i open the app again then two activity gets easily opened help me

Comment: Post your exception. Because I doubt you have issue for some stuff accessing Activity reference in AsyncTask.